# How to weight data using R for dhs domestic violence data (Cote d'Ivoire 2011-2012)

Tags: r, survey, weighted

I would like to set up the survey design for Cote d'Ivoire DHS using R (2011-2012). I am focused on domestic violence.

I used this code:

```
wt <- ipv_studyf$d005/1000000 # creating the variable weight

ipvdesign <- svydesign(ids = ipv_studyf$v021,      # clustering- psu
                        strata = ipv_studyf$v023,   # strata variable
                        weights = wt,               # the weighting variable
                        data = ipv_studyf,          # the dataset
                        variance="HT" )             # Horvitz-Thompson estimator
```

However, I keep getting this error message:

```
**Error in na.weight(data.frame(weights)) : missing values in `weights'**
```

If anyone has any insights on how to set up the dataset in R and help me fix this error message, I would appreciate the help!

Comment: Try by `i1 <- !is.na(wt)`, then do `svydesign(ids = ipv_studyf$v021[i1], strata = ipv_studyf$v023[i1], weights = wt[i1], data = ipv_studyf, variance = "HT")`

Answer (score 0):

We can create a logical vector for `NA`, subset the data and apply the function

```
 i1 <- !is.na(wt)
 svydesign(ids = ipv_studyf$v021[i1], 
           strata = ipv_studyf$v023[i1], 
           weights = wt[i1], 
           data = ipv_studyf, variance = "HT")
```

Comment: Thanks so much, @akrun! It runs well.